# Try catch in c# for divide by zero error

Tags: c#, error-handling

How to do a try catch in c# so that I execute a sql query inside the try catch

Sometimes the value of count is 0, and it throws a error divide by zero error. 
So when it throws the divide by zero error I have to execute a sql statement to delete that statement and and the loop has to continue to get the value of the next record. How can i do it.

```
double value = (read * 100 / count);
```

Comment: Can you show some more code about the sql statement?

Comment: Why is `value` a `double` when the result of your calculation is an `int`?

Comment: catch(DivideByZeroException ex), but as many other write, theres no reason to use try catch... use if instead

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Why doing a try/catch when you can simply test whether the value of `count` is equal to 0:

```
if (count != 0)
{ 
    // perform the division only if count is different than 0,
    // otherwise we know that it will throw an exception 
    // so why even attempting it?
    double value = (read * 100 / count);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, in fact handling exceptions is futile, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.71).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eekeh2z0(v=VS.71).aspx), there will not be any exceptions raised. So, this is the way to go.

Comment: if (count > 0) will be better, negative count (even if a failure, or misstype) is not a valid state

Answer (score 4):

That's conditional logic and shouldn't be handled by an exception.  Perform a check on the value of count before the operation and execute the sql statement accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

you can try like this..

this is sample example

```
namespace nsDivZero
{
    using System;
    public class DivZero
    {
        static public void Main ()
        {
            // Set an integer equal to 0
            int IntVal1 = 0;
            // and another not equal to zero
            int IntVal2 = 57;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("{0} / {1} = {2}", IntVal2, IntVal1, IntResult (IntVal2, IntVal1) / IntResult (IntVal2, IntVal1));
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
            }
            // Set a double equal to 0
            double dVal1 = 0.0;
            double dVal2 = 57.3;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("{0} / {1} = {2}", dVal2, dVal1, DoubleResult (dVal2, dVal1));
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
            }
        }
        static public int IntResult (int num, int denom)
        {
            return (num / denom);
        }
        static public double DoubleResult (double num, double denom)
        {
            return (num / denom);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 : Not the best answer, but for actually showing how to try/catch like the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a try catch in this situation would it not be better to check if the count is 0. Something along the lines of

```
if (count == 0)
{
    DeleteStatement();
    continue;
}

double value = (read * 100 / count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using if statements or try/catch statements I prefer to add `double.Epsilon` to the divider. If working with floats you can also use `float.Epsilon`. It represents the smallest possible number greater than zero and it won't really affect your result. I use this when generating reports and charts

`double value = (read * 100 / (count + double.Epsilon));`

Comment: `public string OpenRate => $"{Read / (Sent + double.Epsilon):P}"` is an easy way to do this with modern c# expression bodied members (can easily use P0 for 45% or P1 for 25.2% etc)

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception is called a RuntimeException in Java (I know this is C#), which means that it should be prevented in the first place, not caught in a catch. Just test that count is not 0.

Comment: `double` will not raise an exception in C#, According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.71).aspx), None of the floating-point operators do.

Comment: Ok, but I was saying to prevent it anyway. I was making an analogy with Java to show that there they differentiate between checked exceptions and runtime exceptions to indicate that the latter should be prevented, not caught.

Comment: Yes, even more so, if there will be no exceptions raised.

Answer (score 0):

`if (count > 0)//as suggested by sasjaq
{ 
  double value = (read * 100 / count);
}`

Seems like a good way to do it. Using try catch will potentially lower performance noticeably...

Answer (score -1):

if the value that you are passing is 0 by any chance and you are doing a division on it, you can get around it just by doing the following:

```
int x = 0; 

int z = 1300;
```

if divided by 0 you will pass infinity value else you pass the correct amount that you want based on the division!

```
int result = x == 0 ? 99999 : x / z; 

Console.WriteLine(result);
```