# Call the method in the constructor after the initialization

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

The CalcTradePrice method should be called right after Trade object's initialization. Right now, it is being called before that, which leads to an exception:

> System.DivideByZeroException: 'Attempted to divide by zero.'

```cs
var trade = new Trade
{
    Pair = pair,
    OpenRate = buyCandle.Close,
    OpenDate = buyCandle.OpenTime,
    Amount = 12345,
    OpenFee = _backtestOptions.OpenFee,
    CloseFee = _backtestOptions.CloseFee,
    IsOpen = true
};
```

I know I can manually call the method after the initialization, just like that:

```cs
var trade = new Trade
{
    Pair = pair
};
CalcTradePrice();
```

or to create a derived class which executes it, but I don't want to. Any recommendations?

#### The Trade class:

```cs
public class Trade
{
    public string Pair { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenTradePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
    public SellType SellType { get; set; }
    
    public Trade()
    {
        CalcTradePrice();
    }
    
    public void CalcTradePrice()
    {
        this.OpenTradePrice = ... // DivideByZeroException because all elements are null at that moment
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try catch in c# for divide by zero error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093919/try-catch-in-c-sharp-for-divide-by-zero-error)

Comment: `Amount = currentBalance / buyCandle.Close,` Make `Amount` a function, not a property. Store `CurrentBalance` as a property.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, ignore the Amount property, it's not the case, as I tried to set it to a hard-coded value. The problem is that the constructor is being called before the `new Trade { Pair = pair, .... }`.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create parameterized constructor. Assign all properties through parameters passed to constructor.Use these properties to calculate trade price in `CalcTradePrice()` function.

```
public class Trade
{
    ...
    
    //I just passed two properties as an example, you can pass all required properties.
    public Trade(int currentBalance, int candleCloseValue)
    {
        this.CurrentBalance = currentBalance;
        this.CandleCloseValue= candleCloseValue;
        CalcTradePrice();
    }
    
    public void CalcTradePrice()
    {
        this.OpenTradePrice = this.CurrentBalance/this.CandleCloseValue; 
    }
}
```

While creating object of Trade class, pass values as a parameter like,

```
var currentBalance = 100;
var candleCloseValue = 20;  
Trade trade = new Trade(currentBalance , candleCloseValue);
```

*Note: I used above two properties just to show, how you can assign property values before calling `CalcTradePrice()` function.*

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer

Comment: I am glad, my answer helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class Trade
{
    public string Pair { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenTradePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
    public SellType SellType { get; set; }
    
    public Trade(buyCandle,_backtestOptions, ..and so on )
    {

    Pair = pair,
    OpenRate = buyCandle.Close;
    OpenDate = buyCandle.OpenTime;
    Amount = currentBalance / buyCandle.Close;
    OpenFee = _backtestOptions.OpenFee;
    CloseFee = _backtestOptions.CloseFee;
    IsOpen = true;

     CalcTradePrice();

     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception `System.DivideByZeroException: 'Attempted to divide by zero.'`
may be triggered by

> Amount = currentBalance / buyCandle.Close

rather than your constructor call.

Comment: No, it's not. I tried to put a hard-coded value.